# Is a blank export of database usable?

Tags: mysql, database, export, backup, recovery

I got a export of my database and I didn't see it. I just copy/pasted it on the flash memory and changed OS *(windows)*. as you know changing the OS causes removing all C drive *(also all databases)*. Unfortunately and sadly, now I'm seeing that export and figure out it is a blank page :-( As a note, I got that export by using `mysqldump` comment in CMD.

[This is that export](https://ufile.io/8cd6). As you see it has 738kb size but it contains only white spaces.

Noted that I used xampp phpmyadmin. Now what should I do? I really don't remember what tables, triggers, events were .. so I cannot recreate them.

Any suggestion?

Comment: The simple answer to your question is that a blank export of a database is not usable. Without a backup of any form - then you will have to start from scratch.

Comment: If that dump file was the only backup, my only suggestions are to cry for a while and then start rebuilding.